# 100% Discount for matching products with discount code, Max qty 1 per product, Maximum fixed total, with 5 items

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, discount, rules

We have a clothing shop and are offering the following discount with a code to select customers only...
1 Free Sweatshirt (any size)
1 Free Polo (any size)
1 Free Fleece (any size)
1 Free Coat (any size)
1 Free PE Polo or Rugbyshirt (any size)
any quantity above 1 will be charged at full price. The issue I have is that if they add a small then a medium in to the cart it see's it as a different product and applies the discount to both instead of one. example below...

This i have got working...
1 Free Sweatshirt Small £10 each
1 Free Polo Small £8 each
1 Free Fleece Small £12 each
1 Free Coat Small £20 each
1 Free Rugbyshirt Small £18 each
Total for cart £68.00
With discount £0.00

This isn't working...
1 Free Sweatshirt Small £10 each
1 Free Polo Small £8 each
1 Free Fleece Small £12 each
1 Free Coat Small £20 each
1 Free Coat Medium £20 each <-Second item should be charged for!!!
1 Free Rugbyshirt Small £18 each
Total for cart £88.00
With discount £20.00 <-should be
With discount £0.00 <-Actually

This is Magento 2.2.2 
I have setup an attribute on the products with the following...
Sweatshirt (all sizes) = SS
Polos (all sizes) = PO
Fleeces (all sizes) = FL
Coats (all sizes) = CO
PE Polo & Rugbyshirts (all sizes) = PE
I was hoping to set quantity as 1 in the rule for each attribute ie SS,PO,FL,CO,PE and when it detects a second SS it would charge full price but because the SKU is different it see's this as a different row and reaplies the SS rule and the second one also goes free. Hope this all makes sense.

Current Rule is setup as follows...
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Discount Helper  contains  SS 
    Quantity in cart  is  1 

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Discount Helper  contains  PO 
    Quantity in cart  is  1 

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Quantity in cart  is  1 
    Discount Helper  is one of  CO 

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Discount Helper  contains  FL 
    Quantity in cart  is  1 

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Discount Helper  contains  PE 
    Quantity in cart  is  1
```

Regards 
Alan